# CMD and windows ID

Tags: cmd, registry

I have been Googling and nothing. Could you tell me how I can get the Windows Product ID with cmd because I want to use this if I dont want someone to use my program the program will exit. Thanks

Comment: what language are you using?  we might be able to provide you an alternative.  The language you are using might even support OS specific settings like `version`

Answer (score 0):

You can read the Product Id from the registry like this:

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductId
```

On more recent Windows versions you could also get the information from the `systeminfo` command:

```
systeminfo | find /i "product id:"
```

Comment: ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

Comment: @Adrianvdh Apparently Microsoft removed the information from the `Windows` subkey in more recent versions. Reading the `Windows NT` subkey should still work, though.

Answer (score 0):

`wmic` can get you the product ID.

```
wmic os get serialnumber
```

To scrape it to a variable:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get serialnumber /format:list') do set productid=%%I
```