# CMD and finding ProductID

Tags: cmd

Hello everyone I am writing this script to find the product ID of a computer and if it is true it will say you are banned...

```
wmic os get "SerialNumber"|find /v "SerialNumber" >>%IDcheckfile% | findstr /i "****-OEM-*********-*****"
cls
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('"SerialNumber"') do set "productID=%%i"

goto STARTLOG )
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (echo You are banned from this program )
pause
exit
```

Now that is great but I need to copy the ID from the text file and I am struggling to do that. Let me know if I even need to save to ID to a text file. Why I need to extract the ID and stroe it in a varible is because it need to show the ID in the programs log. Many Thanks for your awesome help so far :) and Thanks you for this one!

Comment: Where can I learn the for /f commands because I dont understand it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CMD and windows ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500892/cmd-and-windows-id)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductID^|find "REG_SZ"') do set "ProductID=%%j"
if defined ProductID (echo.ProductID: %ProductID%) else echo You are banned!
endlocal
```

Comment: Sorry it doesnt work. What I need is to get the product ID and store it in a varible. And I will use my own code to display that varible in a log... [code] wmic os get "SerialNumber"|find /v "SerialNumber" >>%IDcheckfile% | findstr /i "*****-OEM-********-*****"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (cls
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductID^|find "REG_SZ"') do set "productID=%%i"
goto STARTLOG )
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (cls
echo You are banned from this program )
pause
exit ) [/code]

Comment: Nvm I tried and struggled and it work, but Thanks for trying to help me, I appreciate it. Here the right code: wmic os get "SerialNumber"|find /v "SerialNumber" >>%IDcheckfile% | findstr /i "*****-OEM-*****-*****"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (cls
for /f "tokens=3" %%p in ('reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductID') do set "productID=%%p"
goto STARTLOG )
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (cls
echo You are banned from this program )
pause
exit )

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO off
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('wmic os get SerialNumber^|find "-"') DO SET productid=%%i
ECHO %productid%|FIND "-OEM-" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO OEM version - banned&GOTO end
ECHO productid=%productid%
:startlog

:end

pause
```

FOR /f reads the file nominated between the parentheses line-by-line

- Skipping empty lines - that is lines containing NO characters and
  lines beginning ";"
- The "file" may in fact be the `output` of a command. Simply enclose the command in `single quotes` Pipes and other special characters need to be escaped by a caret (`^`)
  The textline read is then split into `TOKENS`. Each token is delimited by er, `DELIMITERS`
- By default, the delimiters are `space`, `comma`, `semicolon`, `tab` but can be varied to "any" set of SINGLE characters by listing those characters between the `=` and `"` of the `"delims=abc"` clause (which would set `a`,`b`,`c` as delimiters.
- By default, only token 1 (the er, first token on the line) is assigned, and it will be assigned to the `metavariable` (ie the loop-control letter - `i` in the above example)
- By using a `tokens=` clause and listing the token numbers (separated by commas) other tokens can be assigned. The lowest-numbered token is assigned to the `metavariable`, the next lowest-numbered to the succeeding metavariable, and so on - so `"tokens=1,3delims=-` will assign tokens 1 and 3 from the line to `%%i` and `%%j` respectively if the **FOR** metavariable is `i`.
- As a special, token `*` means "the rest of the line after the last token specified"

Essentially, that's it. There are heaps of extra facilities you can apply in addition - filename fracturing into drive,path,name,extension or size, datetime, attributes and so on for instance. All documented in the easy-to-read `FOR /?` from the prompt...

Comment: 1. `for /F` can also read immediate strings and command outputs (_stdout_). 2. The default delimiters are _space_ and _tab_ only! 3. Perhaps you should mention that lines containing delimiters only are considered as empty.